# Is there a Python or PHP library which can Tokenise and Convert Japanese text

Tags: php, python

Given a string that can contain Japanse and English text, I would like to:

1. Convert the Japanese parts from Hiragana to Katakana and half width to full width.
2. Split the string by words (Japanse text does not use spaces to delimit words)

I am currently using the excellent iOS / OS X string libraries (which cater for hundreds of complexities and edge cases).

[`CFStringTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform) with the `kCFStringTransformHiraganaKatakana` constant.

[`enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateSubstringsInRange%3aoptions%3ausingBlock%3a) with the `NSStringEnumerationByWords` constant.

The search is moving from client to server so we need a PHP or Python version of these methods.

Comment: Just found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jcconv/0.1.2 for task 1

Answer (score 0):

maybe [nltkjp](https://code.google.com/p/nltkjp/) or [tiny segmenter](https://github.com/miyamuko/tiny-segmenter), both compatibles with [nltk](http://nltk.org/),
for japanese corpora you can visit [Masato Hagiwara](http://lilyx.net/nltk-japanese-corpus/) site.